# Can I export a PDF from Blender?

Tags: export

I would like to have a way of getting the design sheets(aka blueprints) like you can in CAD software.

Is there a plugin or addon or some form of python script that can export a PDF(vector screenshot) of the GUI(primarily the 3D view)?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want the geometric data with dimensioned drawing or just the wireframe of your object? E.g. http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/e/e1/Manual-2.6-Render-Freestyle-Demo-BluePrint.png

Comment: This isn't currently possible out of the box with Blender or with any addons atm, I could however suggest looking at MeshLab.. it can export to `.u3d` which can be converted to pdf. http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Could you link to an image (or a PDF file) which shows an example of what you would like to achieve? - PDF can contain lots of different kinds of data so its hard to guess at what you want. Are you expecting this to be wireframe or shaded for example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [SVGWriter for Blender/Freestyle](http://www.geocities.jp/blenderyard/freestyle/svgwriter_b26/README.html)

> The SVGWriter package provides a set of Python script files for authoring SVG documents with Blender and Freestyle.

Nowadays, [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)s are more portable than PDF, with support in all major browsers. There are also many free tools that can convert them to PDF if that's required. One such program is [PDFAid](http://www.pdfaid.com/svg-to-pdf-conversion.aspx).

Comment: The main link is broken, better replace with https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/render_freestyle_svg.html

Comment: @MarcosSaito  Your link has become broken too.

Answer (score 5):

To your question:
- Not directly but they are an addon to export the viewport in svg:
"Export SVG" by Liero ->
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script
and in Inkscape, you can export in pdf normally! And voilà!

Comment: With an svg python library like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input) one, it's easy enough to generate pdf from svg too!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer suggested the Freestyle SVG plugin; the current URL at time of writing is: 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html

The key bit of advice from that URL is:

> This add-on can be enabled via Preferences ‣ Add-ons ‣ Render ‣
>   Freestyle SVG Exporter. The GUI for the exporter should now be visible
>   in the render tab of the Properties editor. The exported .svg file is
>   written to the default output path Properties ‣ Output ‣ Output.

The SVG is exported upon rendering the view to the specified output folder, in addition to the regular output.

Another stack exchange [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114875/freestyle-wireframe-svg-export-workaround) describes some useful settings for exporting the wireframe view appearance: in Blender 2.8 in Layout view, if you open up the 'View Layer Properties' pane, change visibility to 'QI range'.

Answer (score 2):

At present, there is no such addon/plugin that I'm aware of. You can see which addons are currently available publicly on the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts)

If all you want to do is convert a collection of images to pdf then there are several python pdf libraries to choose from, i've used [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) to generate a pdf from a [directory of images](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/4962354). But this might be considered off topic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your question has two parts: 
1) can I export to pdf?
and 2) can I generate blueprints with blender?

The answer to both are no, not with some extra steps (i.e. no script or addons, you'd have to do it manually using [Orthographic](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View) view.)

To actually make the image, you might want to render in [wireframe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73W8Eook78M), (or do screencapture) then Export an image and make your pdf with that. (For screencapture on Windows, press "PrntScn" and then "Ctrl-V" in Paint or Photoshop to capture the GUI, before you last edit you were asking for a GUI capture.)

addendum: You might want to get in contact with these people: [Blueprints Collection](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/06/12/blueprint-repository/#utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+Blendernation+%28BlenderNation%29)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a fine answer, but he is asking for a way to make a vector screenshot/blueprint. Please try to answer questions that will solve original posters problem.

Comment: the words `blueprint` and `vector screenshot` were added by people other than the OP, it's difficult to tell exactly what the OP wants without his response.

Comment: what about ANSI sheets. like in autocad? i'm autocad-autolisp certified either if a "blueprint" likes it or not.