# Freestyle Wireframe SVG Export Workaround?

Tags: freestyle, wireframe, svg

Little disclaimer: I don't have much experience with Blender or 3D modelling at all, just downloaded the program last week.

My goal is to create polyhedra, then render out the wireframe as a SVG.

I found that using the Freestyle SVG Export add on this seemed possible.

The problem I ran into was that it didn't work when I'd use the Wire material type. I tried using the wireframe modifier and that looked like it worked at first. But, after importing the svg into a vector graphics editor and lowering the line width, turns out each "edge" on the wireframe was actually a stretched cube (or whatever the term is):
[image]

I found a work around, but it's very tedious. I removed the wireframe modifier and just rendered the visible faces, then manually removed the faces surrounding each "layer," and exported those. In the end I layered them all together and got the final image on the bottom right. It's a bit difficult to explain, so here's a picture:
[image]

Again, very tedious..... Is there a better workaround? Or am I missing something?

Also, is there any way to preview the SVG render? What I'm doing now is rendering after changing something, then opening the SVG file on chrome to check if it had any effect... kinda inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted by changing the visibility setting on the FreeStyle Line Set section of the Render Layers panel from "Visible" to "QI Range"

[image]

which apparently stands for "Quantitative Invisibility Range".
I don't really know what this means but it worked, would appreciate if someone could clarify!

Comment: Although the wording is confusing, the picture of the documentation probably gives you enough information. The tooltip is slightly easier to understand: "*Select feature edges within a range of [...] values.*"

Comment: This answer helped me too... now I am looking for a way to export a SVG of lines of the mesh of the object, can't seem to find how