# Generate 2D engineering drafts based on 3D model

Tags: 2d

Is there a way to automatically generate such detailed 2D engineering drafts from a 3D model:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90192/making-diagrams-and-blueprints-for-engineering

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/766/can-i-export-a-pdf-from-blender